# module thats not producing output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, scripting

> Heres is the main driver code.

```
import Proj05Runner

str = 'The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence.'
subStr = 'fox'
result = Proj05Runner.run(str,subStr)
print(result)
```

> Here is the code i have so far of the module that needs to work with the driver.

```
def run(str, subStr):
"""Returns a substring of any given string based upon a given range of characters before and after the substring"""

str_range = 3

if subStr in str:
    str_modified = str[str.index(subStr) - str_range : str.index(subStr) + len(subStr) + str_range]
    return ("I certify that this program is my own work " + "\n" + str + "\n" + subStr + "\n" + str_modified +
            "and is not the work of others. I agree not " + "\n" + str + "\n" + subStr + "\n" + str_modified +
            "to share my solution with others. " + "\n" + str + "\n" + subStr + "\n" + str_modified +
            "Print your name here." + "\n" + str + "\n" + subStr + "\n" + str_modified)
else:
    return "ERROR: subStr not found in str!"
```

> the output hasn't been producing right, for example

```
I certify that this program is my own work 
The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence.
fox
wn fox juand is not the work of others. I agree not 
The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence.
fox
wn fox juto share my solution with others. 
The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence.
fox
wn fox juPrint your name here.
The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence.
fox
wn fox ju
```

> heres output i need it to produce

```
I certify that this program is my own work
and is not the work of others. I agree not
to share my solution with others.
Print your name here.

The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence.
fox
wn fox ju

im sorry guys im new to this..
```

Comment: That's not the right way to have a string that spans across several lines of code.

Comment: the problem with your code is you cannot call `str()`  within `run` (or anywhere really)

Comment: the lesser problem, is that code is not being indented properly

Comment: i somewhat made it run now but its not producing the output correctly

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need:

```
def run(str, subStr):
    """Returns a substring of any given string based upon a given range of characters before and after the substring"""

    str_range = 3
    
    if subStr in str:
        str_modified = str[str.index(subStr) - str_range : str.index(subStr) + len(subStr) + str_range]
        return ("I certify that this program is my own work \nand is not the work of others. I agree not \nto share my solution with others.\nPrint your name here.\n\n" + str + "\n" + subStr + "\n" + str_modified)
    else:
        return "ERROR: subStr not found in str!"

str = 'The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence.'
subStr = 'fox'
out = run(str, subStr)
print (out)
```

Output:

```
I certify that this program is my own work 
and is not the work of others. I agree not 
to share my solution with others.
Print your name here.

The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence.
fox
wn fox ju
```